# How can I fetch every member's permissions

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
var list = await client.guilds.cache.get(guild.id);
list.members.cache.array().forEach((member) => {
    let Member = member.id;
    if (guild.me.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS") && guild.me.roles.highest.rawPosition > Member.roles.highest.rawPosition) {
        console.log(`--------------Members--------------\n${Member.tag} | can be banned`);
    }
    if (guild.me.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS") && guild.me.roles.highest.rawPosition < Member.roles.highest.rawPosition) {
        console.log(`${Member.tag} | cant be banned`);
    }
})
```

I have tried this code *it's in a ready event* so it tells me which users can be banned, and yes **guild** has been defined as a *forEach* so it fetches every guild.

Comment: Whats the Error what you get?

Comment: Why don't you use the [`kickable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=kickable) or [`bannable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=bannable) flag?

Answer (score 0):

Here’s something that may work:

```js
let guild = client.guilds.cache.get('…');
let info = guild.members.cache.map(m => `${m.user.tag} ${m.bannable ? 'can be banned' : 'cannot be banned'}`);
//info is array
```